# How can i make icons hover on layout which will also be clickable

Tags: android

I've designed a page using a wheel menu bar. Wheel menu bar circled very good. But I want to  when icons come at liner layout on top of the page, it should be know which image is hovering. And it should be click able. I write algorithm

1)  I want to put liner layout on top of the page

2)  when icons(this are image) come on this liner layout it should be click able

3)  this layout should know which button on hover

** xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/cell_bg"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, GAMA!" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/belirtec9_2bg"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
    >

    <com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel
        android:id="@+id/wheel"
        android:paddingTop="10px" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**...... code**

```
package com.myproject.gama;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel;
import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.WheelAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.util.Log;

public class SampleWheelActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = SampleWheelActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Wheel wheel;
    public WheelAdapter<Adapter> adapter;
    private Resources res; 
    public int[] icons = { 
         R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon0 , R.drawable.icon2};
    ImageView t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);       
        wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
        wheel.setWheelDiameter(400);


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){


        //yöntem0
                String arrayStr = Arrays.toString (icons);
                String[] strArray = new String[] {arrayStr};


        super.onResume();
    }



    private OnClickListener onClick() {
         Toast.makeText(SampleWheelActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }



    private Drawable[] getDrawableFromData(int[] data) {
        Drawable[] ret = new Drawable[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = res.getDrawable(data[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }

/*  void onItemClick(WheelAdapter<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id){
        Log.d(TAG,"OnItemClick");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onItemClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set onclicklistener on each button or view in the layout.

```
wheel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
});
```

Comment: But this icons not on xml they are on drawable folder so drawable not clickable. How can Understand this layout which is on top of. This answer is so general

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your init function

```
wheel.setItemClickEventAtSelectionPosition(false);

wheel.setOnItemClickListener(new WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(WheelAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Comment: yes I know this method but how can reach id.. R.id.icon0 not showing it is not image on layout so how can I reach this icon0 id? could you fill method ?