# Converting string array to ImageButton

Tags: android

First I put them int array I cannot change it due to other process on my code. How can do this string clickable(onClick event). This icons are not my xml. It is on draw able folder.

```
 public int[] icons = { 
         R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon0 , R.drawable.icon2};
    ImageView t;
```

Then I convert them String Array

```
String arrayStr = Arrays.toString (icons);
            String[] aa = arrayStr.split(",");

            for( int i = 0; i < aa.length ; i++)
            {
                String element = aa[0];    

                             //How can do this imageView and clickable
                ImageView  icon1 = (ImageView)element ;

            }
```

Comment: an `String` clickable? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry my bad english.. I put this icons on string array. How can I do this string array elements click events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make clickable items in your drawable folder :) You can make clickable items in your XML layout, so first, you need to create `ImageView` in your XML layout (or via code), assign source drawable to this `ImageView` (that would be one of the items in you `drawable` folder) and then you will be able to add `onClickListener` to your `ImageView`.

So essentially, items in your drawable folder do not have anything to do with Android - they are just resources which you can use in Android layouts. That's why you cannot just have their ids and assign click listener to them

Comment: Yes but I can not put them my xml. I use wheel menu library. How can do this icons which are on draw able folder clickevent

Comment: not important imageview it should be have click event but I can not do this click event :(

Comment: sory my bad English http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236014/how-can-i-make-icons-hover-on-layout-which-will-also-be-clickable this my athor question. I work two thing on this page..

Comment: again, you cannot set onclicklistener to items in `drawable` folder. You can only set click listeners to items in your XML

Comment: thanks. But there are icons id on icons array. Can I do this array elements this clickable ?

Comment: thanks.. I research is there any way.. But you said no. So I try other way thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49186/discussion-between-19052013-and-pavel-dudka)